# Why are there extra terms $-p_i+q_i$ in SciPy's implementation of Kullback-Leibler divergence?

Tags: optimization, information-theory, kullback-leibler, convex

Why do some definitions of the Kullback-Leibler divergence include extra terms $-p_i + q_i$? For example, [`kl_div()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.kl_div.html) (in the Python `scipy.special` module) defines the Kullback-Leibler divergence as
$$
  \sum_i p_i \ln\frac{p_i}{q_i} - p_i + q_i.
$$

The documentation says:

> The origin of this function is in convex programming; see [`[1]`](https://www.cambridge.org/highereducation/books/convex-optimization/17D2FAA54F641A2F62C7CCD01DFA97C4#overview) for details. This is why the function contains the extra terms over what might be expected from the Kullback-Leibler divergence.

I don't have the referenced book at hand. What is the justification or motivation for the additional $-p_i + q_i$ terms?

**Anti-closing note:** This is not a question about software, but about the concept behind it.

Comment: @Firebug I'm unsure whether I understand what you mean. The software is obviously meant to work on discrete distributions. A different function, `rel_entr()` (relative entropy), linked from the above one, relies on the common definition of the KL-divergence for discrete distributions. I'd like to know how and why the additional terms appear.

Comment: The function does not integrate anything, ergo, it does not compute the Kullback-Leibler Divergence.

Comment: @JohnMadden I believe you are talking about the OP question, while I'm talking about `scipy`

Comment: @Firebug Oh, I see what you mean, yes that's confusing that they define an "elementwise" KL divergence.

Comment: I have edited the question so the plea not to be closed goes at the end and a very brief summary of the question (in particular, what the extra terms are) goes at the very start - this is to try and make the question appear more meaningful in search engine snippet results for future readers. (I've also phrased it to make clear that `scipy` isn't the only place you'll see this definition, eg the cited reference uses it too, so this Q will be useful to non-scipy users as well.) Feel free to revert my changes or make further ones if you think it will be useful!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The other answer tells us why we don't usually see the $-p_i+q_i$ term: $p$ and $q$ are usually residents of the simplex and so sum to one, so this leads to $\sum - [p_i - q_i] = \sum - p_i + \sum q_i = -1 + 1 = 0$.

In this answer, I want to show why those terms are there in the first place, by viewing KL divergence as the [Bregman divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bregman_divergence) induced by the (negative) [Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) function.

Given some differentiable function $\psi$, the Bregman divergence induced by it is a binary function on the domain of $\psi$:

$$
B_\psi(p,q) = \psi(p)-\psi(q)-\langle\nabla\psi(q),p-q\rangle
$$

Intuitively, the Bregman divergence measures the difference between $\psi$ evaluated at $p$ and the linear approximation to $\psi$ (about $q$) evaluated at $p$. When $\psi$ is convex, this is guaranteed to be nonnegative, and thus so is the Bregman divergence.

Noting that if $\psi(p) = \sum_i p_i \log p_i$, $\nabla\psi(p) = [\log p_i + 1]$, the entropic Bregman divergence is thus:

$$
B_e(p,q) = \sum_i p_i \log p_i - \sum_i q_i \log q_i - \sum_i [\log q_i + 1][p_i-q_i]\\
= \sum_i p_i \log p_i - \sum_i q_i \log q_i - \sum_i [\log q_i (p_i-q_i) + p_i-q_i]\\
= \sum_i p_i \log p_i - \sum_i q_i \log q_i - \sum_i p_i \log q_i + \sum_i q_i\log q_i - \sum_i[p_i-q_i]\\
= \sum_i p_i \log p_i - \sum_i p_i \log q_i - \sum_i[p_i-q_i]\\
 = \sum_i p_i \log \frac{p_i}{q_i}  + \sum_i[-p_i+q_i]
$$

which we recognize as the KL divergence you mentioned.

Answer (score 22):

The referenced book has a free pdf on Boyd's site: [https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf)

On page 90, formula 3.17 gives this definition. I suspect the reason for the added terms is that in convex optimization, the two vectors needn't be probability distributions; the authors say

> Note that the relative entropy and the Kullback-Leibler divergence
> are the same when $u$ and $v$ are probability vectors

When they are, in the sum the extra terms cancel. But when they aren't, the added terms ensure that the total is nonnegative.